# HTTP get method returns http host connect exception

Tags: httpclient, http-get

I am trying to get the response from a  URI using httpclient and httpget. when i am trying to execute the httpclient.execute method it is giving me the http host connect exception. However when i am passing the same URI to the XML parsing code as inputstream the code works fine.
Does someone has any idea on the problem..
Help appreciated in advance

vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy?  The HttpClient library probably uses a different way to configure the proxy than the XML library you are using.  The following links may be useful, depending on the version of HttpClient you are using.

- http://cephas.net/blog/2007/11/14/java-commons-http-client-and-http-proxies/ (pre 4.0)
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/200902.mbox/%3C499C63D1.1080701@apache.org%3E (4.0)